# Does being big for a line bundle satisfy fpqc descent

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, descent, ample-bundles

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, and let $L/k$ be a field extension. [Assume $k$ and $L$ are algebraically closed if necessary.]

Let $X$ be a variety over $k$ and let $\mathcal{L}$ be a line bundle on $X$ such that the pull-back of $\mathcal{L}$ to $X_L$ is big.

Is $L$ big on $X$?

Replacing "big" by "ample" above, the answer is yes and follows from fpqc descent for ampleness; see Tag 0D2P in the stacks project. I presume that more generally bigness also satisfies fpqc descent. Is that correct?

Comment: Bigness is determined by dimensions of global sections, which is insensitive to base change.